# Convert methods to props using mapped types

Tags: typescript

I need to pick/select from generic objects with multiple generic no-arg functions and return a object holding the evaluated result with correct typing.

For props I can select using the following function signature:

```
function select<T, K extends keyof T>(obj:T,keys:K[]):{[P in K]:T[P]}
```

I want something like this:

```
function select<T, K extends keyof T>(obj:T,keys:K[]):{[P in K]:T[P]()}
```

Notice `T[P]()` in the return type, which does not work, but illustrates my need. K should also be constrained by `keyof T & ()=>U`, where U is different for each method.

Is this possible?

Comment: Afraid the answer is no. Hope someone with more TS internal knowledge will prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).  This lets you express a function *input* as a mapped type and still allow inference to (sometimes) work.

I've often found that TypeScript problems can be solved by tackling an "upside-down" or "backwards" version of the problem.  For example, your issue is that there's not currently (as of TypeScript 2.7) a way to take a function signature and extract the return type.  But there is a way to take a return type and compose a function signature from it, which is "backwards" from what you want.  And inference from mapped types lets you proceed like this:

```
declare function select<T, K extends keyof T>(
  obj: {[P in keyof T]: () => T[P]}, 
  keys: K[]
): {[P in K]: T[P]};
```

So the type `T` isn't the type of `obj` anymore, but rather the type of the return value of `select()` in the case where `K` is the full `keyof T`.  Let's see if it works:

```
const obj = {
  foo: () => 3,
  bar: () => "hey",
  baz: () => false
}

const result = select(obj, ["foo", "baz"]);
// result: { foo: number; baz: boolean; }
```

If you inspect the code, you'll see that the compiler infers the generic parameters as `T={ foo: number; bar: string; baz: boolean; }` and `K="foo"|"baz"`... and hence the result is `{ foo: number; baz: boolean; }` as you want.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Amazing, it works :) Rebinding T this way seems a bit strange. Do you know if this is legal/specified behavior or something undefined that may change for 2.8+?

Comment: It's definitely intended to allow you to use inference from mapped types to make functions "backwards" like that, although I don't know if they anticipated this particular use case.  I was a little worried that it wouldn't work, since the bare `T` doesn't appear as the type of any particular parameter or the return value... but I guess it does.

Comment: It does :) Thanks!